# How to pass argument to a function from a pipe output of another using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have written a function called Wait-UntilJobFailOrSuccess . This takes the output from  Get-Job using pipe command line. For example.

```
 Get-Job|Remove-Job
```

The same way I want to do for my function. For example

```
Get-Job | Wait-UntilJobFailOrSuccess
```

I also attached Wait-UntilJobFailOrSuccess below. Please let us know. Do anyone has a solution for this.

```
Function Wait-UntilJobFailOrSuccess
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [System.Object[]]$jobs
        )
    while ($true) {
     if ('Failed' -in $jobs.State) {
        $jobs | Stop-Job 
        Write-Host "Aborting Jobs ${result}"
        break
    }

    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
  }

  foreach ($job in $jobs) {
        if ($job.State -eq 'Failed') {
        Write-Host ($job.ChildJobs[0].JobStateInfo.Reason.Message) -ForegroundColor Red
    } else {
        Write-Host (Receive-Job $job) -ForegroundColor Green 
    }
  }
  $jobs|remove-Job
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to accept the pipeline input in your function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for what exactly? You haven't stated a problem.

Anyway, in your code you name you your parameter "Jobs" then make it as `[ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName]`. Job objects don't have a `Jobs` property so this will not work. Consider a separate parameter `Id` for this. Also, rather than typing the parameter as `[object[]]`, type it as `[System.Management.Automation.Job[]]` which is the type of the job object.

You should have logic in the `process` block to accumulate all of the `Job` objects then move the loops to the `end` block once all of the jobs have been gathered.

I've reformatted your code and cleaned it up a bit, but I still can't figure out what you're actually trying to do:

```
Function Wait-UntilJobFailOrSuccess
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [System.Management.Automation.Job[]]
            $jobs
    )

    begin
    {
        $joblist = @()
    }

    process 
    {
        $joblist += $jobs
    }

    end
    {
        foreach ($job in $joblist)
        {
            if ($job.State -eq 'Failed') 
            {
                Stop-Job -Job $job 
                Write-Host "Aborting Job $(job.name)"
                break
            }
        }

        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500

        foreach ($job in $jobslist) 
        {
            if ($job.State -eq 'Failed')
            {
                Write-Host ($job.ChildJobs[0].JobStateInfo.Reason.Message) -ForegroundColor Red
            } 
            else 
            {
                Write-Host (Receive-Job $job) -ForegroundColor Green
            } 
        }
        $joblist | Remove-Job -Force # Is this what you really want to do?
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I modified the code what you suggested. I will tell you why I need to use the pipe.  I'm having a lot of script block. As of now, I'm creating a variable called $jobs and getting all the jobs to a variable and then calling Wait-UntilJobFailOrSuccess. Just reduce this complexity I was trying to use the pipe. But it is not working for me.

Comment: Adding to above command, We can't take the pipe output as [System.Management.Automation.Job[]] in powershell from Get-Job command? is it like I need to explicity specificy what all column I required?

Comment: @Vipin A better practice is to either be explicit with your types (`[object[]]` isn't descriptive) or let the interpreter figure out the types implicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions BrucePayette. I'm very new to PowerShell. I did not know that there is something begin, process and end in PowerShell methods. If my questions confuse you sorry for that. I think I got my answers from your comments. Thank you so much once again for @TheIncorrigible1